# Code reuse in type-bound procedures and ambiguous generic binding

Tags: fortran, derived-types

I am using derived types in fortran to declare position and 
vector types. Elements are stored in array p.

A problem I am having in when coding the derived type `Vec`.
How can I reuse the procedure `pos_set` using Type `vec`. Seems 
I would have to copy over the code. I essentially want to
populate the array `p`, irrespective whether the type is 
`Pos` or `Vec`.

Furthermore I get an error when I try to use same generic
name for both types.

```
Generic :: set => pos_set
Generic :: set => vec_set
```

Here are the difinitions

```
Type Pos
  Integer, Allocatable :: p(:)

Contains
  Procedure :: pos_set
  Generic :: set => pos_set

End Type Pos

Type, Extends (Pos) :: Vec
Contains
  Procedure :: vec_set
  Generic :: set => vec_set
End Type Vec

Subroutine pos_set (t, u, v, w) 
  Class (Pos), Intent (InOut) :: t
  Integer, Intent (In) :: u
  Integer, Intent (In), Optional :: v, w

  Integer :: ct

  Call scan (ct, u, v, w)
  Call newp (t, ct)

  t% p(1) = u
  If (Present (v)) t% p(2) = v
  If (Present (w)) t% p(3) = w

End Subroutine pos_set
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Furthermore, what is the difference between `pos_set` and `vec_set`?

Comment: Error: 'vec_set' and 'pos_set' for GENERIC 'set' at (1) are ambiguous

Comment: Nothing is different from the two except that the input objects will be different, one will be `Pos` and the other `Vec`.

Comment: So you have your answer, I guess. If these functions are ambiguous, how could the compiler decide which one to choose? Why don't you simply inherit the setter function, then?

Comment: That's my question, how can I inherit it from `Pos`

Comment: I suggest you define an `abstract` base type for both `Pos` and `Vec` where `set` is a deferred type-bound procedure with an explicit interface. That way, `Pos` and `Vec` are both siblings from the parent type with a common generic type-binding.

Comment: That would still have me replicate essentially the same code I think.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you just omit `Procedure :: vec_set` and `Generic :: set => vec_set`?

Comment: Seems to work. I just call `set` and even if the subroutine `position_set` takes `Class (Position)`, Vector is accepted. Same with using `get`.

Comment: @Zeus Why do you think so? The implementation of `vec_set` and `pos_set` are deferred while other non-deferred procedures using `set` may be implemented in the declaration of the base type `Parent`. Are you familiar with `type, abstract`?

Comment: Have not used `type, abstract` before